# How can I read process output without blocking?

Tags: java

I start child process from Java using `ProcessBuilder`. Child process may run forever and writes data to stdout from time to time.

I want to read this data from the parent process and do some other things.

It seems that I can't use NIO Selector to read `inputStream` of my process, is it right?

So, I need to read it on separate thread using blocking `read()`. But then I can't stop this thread (until I kill process) because `Thread.interrupt` doesn't work for blocked threads. And I need to stop it somehow and leave process alive.

The only solution I see is loop:

1. check `InputStream.available()`
2. `InputStream.read()` (if any data is actually available)
3. `Thread.sleep()` for a while.
4. go to 1

I can lose some data (because of buffer overflow) if I sleep too long. And without of step 3 you spent CPU cycles for nothing.

What is the correct solution here?

Comment: I would have said let the thread do its blocking read and kill the process to kill the thread. What's the use case for stopping the thread without also stopping the process?

Comment: What is I want my application to be closed leaving child process run? Can I use daemon threads for it?

Comment: If you sleep too long _and_ the child process tries to write more than the pipe capacity, it hangs until you wake up and read; **no data will be lost**, but slowing the child process may or may not be problematic.

Comment: Do you mean that ``print`` will be blocked?